# Переопределение процедуры при наследовании

Tags: ооп, наследование, delphi

Добрый день!

Есть класс, в котором определен массив и порядок работы с ним. При каждом изменении массива он должен выводиться на форму. Для этого в классе есть процедура Show:

```
type

DataArray = class
    protected
        Data: Array [0..1000] of integer;
    public
        procedure Change;
        procedure Show;

implementation

procedure DataArray.Change;
begin
    // изменяем массив
    Show; // Показываем
end;

procedure DataArray.Show;
begin
    // а вот тут ничего, сейчас объясню
end;
```

Так как формы бывают разными, я решил для каждой наследовать этот класс и определять свой метод Show.

Однако процедура Change вызывает не тот метод, что определен в потомке, а тот, что ничего не делает.

Подскажите, как с этим быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все-таки после создания поста на хэшкоде поиск в гугле начинает выводить верные результаты =)

Я определил `Show` как `dynamic` и в наследнике перезаписал ее `override`.

Теперь вопрос: есть ли тут подводные грабли? Что нужно знать и учитывать при работе с такими функциями?

Comment: подводные грабли нитко не говорит - говорят, подводные камни.

Comment: если вы осилили поиск в гугле один раз, то почему бы не попробовать еще раз?

Comment: подводные грабли так-же неожиданны как грабли, но находятся под водой, поэтому к шоку добавляется ещё и недоумение: "что они здесь делают?, кто их сюда положил?"

Comment: @voipp, ну давайте тогда закроем этот и еще несколько сотен других форумов. Тут же 80% вопросов гуглится! Конечно, на форуме программистов нужно обсуждать кто, как и что сказал, да.

Comment: >подводные грабли нитко не говорит - говорят, подводные камни

Нашли к чему прицепиться. Тут вообще энное количество участников русским языком не владеет даже на уровне 5 класса средней школы. Если так, то и ваше сообщение было далеко не безупречно -  у вас со знаками препинания явно беда. Ну и потом, по-моему, это не ошибка, а что-то вроде каламбура. Например, есть такое небезызвестное одесское выражение "две большие разницы". Оно, строго говоря, некорректно с точки зрения стилистики русского языка. Однако ж существует

Comment: Правильнее не `dynamic`, а `virtual`. Они оба дают возможность переопределять метод, но по-разному. Если интересно в чем отличие, почитайте справку (там много буков) или загуглите.